# Probability - cube stacking

Tags: probability

How can I approach this problem?

[image: probability problem]

All possible variations are $10!$, right? But what is the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider blue cubes and green cubes separately.

The answer is 
$$\frac{6!\cdot 4!}{10!}=\frac{1}{210}.$$

The denominator $10!$ means you treat 10 cubes as distinct cubes. Then, since the places for the cubes in each color are determined, consider each of blue cubes and green cubes separately.